# What is the average number of steps to reach a destination?

Tags: probability

Lets say that a system has $3$ steps and the probability of going to $$\text{STEP}_1\longrightarrow \text{STEP}_2 \quad\text{ is }\, 0.5\phantom{0}$$ and that of $$\text{STEP}_2\longrightarrow \text{STEP}_3 \quad \text{ is } \,\,0.25$$ If you fail at $\text{STEP}_1$, you stay at $\text{STEP}_1$ and also if you fail at $\text{STEP}_2$, you still come back to $\text{STEP}_1$. What would be the average number of steps to reach $\text{STEP}_3$ from $\text{STEP}_1$?

I know this can be done using Markov Chain Expectancy but I'm finding it difficult to formulate.

Answer (score 2):

For each $1\le i \le 3$ define $h(i)$ to be the expected number of steps you need until you reach state $3$. Thus, $$h(1)=1+0.5\cdot h(2)+0.5\cdot h(1)$$ $$h(2)=1+0.25\cdot h(3)+0.75\cdot h(1)$$ and $h(3)=0$. Now solve recursively the system of equations to determine $h(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed Markov. $\frac{1}{1-p}$ with $p$ the escape probability is the expected number of steps in this simple example. You can also add the numbers in this example, so 2 + 4 = 6

Comment: There's a slight edit in the question. Please check.

Comment: With the edit: Intuitively, you need 2 steps from 1 to 2, you need 3 failing iterations of 1 + 2 steps via 1 back to 2 in 2. Then you need 1 more step to reach 3 successfully: 2 + 3*3 + 1 = 12. Which is also the result of the other solution.